# Why I get exception when I try to create polygon using DbGeometry?

Tags: c#, .net, gis, geospatial, geocoding

Here how I try to create polygon using DbGeometry:

```
 var t = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry.PolygonFromText("POLYGON(184124.95503725 666736.70253002, 184116.48837516 665712.23641656, 184946.22126044 666304.90276319, 184124.95503725 666736.70253002)", 2039);
```

when the row above executed I get this exception message:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

innerException:

```
24142: Expected "(" at position 8. The input has "1".
```

Any idea why I get exception above?

Comment: will it work? : `var t = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry.PolygonFromText("POLYGON((184124.95503725 666736.70253002, 184116.48837516 665712.23641656, 184946.22126044 666304.90276319, 184124.95503725 666736.70253002))", 2039);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you didn't add parentheses:

```
var t = System.Data.Spatial.DbGeometry.PolygonFromText("POLYGON((184124.95503725 666736.70253002, 184116.48837516 665712.23641656, 184946.22126044 666304.90276319, 184124.95503725 666736.70253002))", 2039);
```

see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text:

```
POLYGON ((30 10, 40 40, 20 40, 10 20, 30 10))
```